# VSCode: order problems top to bottom rather than errors first, then warnings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use the command: `editor.action.marker.next` and `editor.action.marker.prev` to move between errors in my code. However, instead of moving to the closest "problem", it moves to the "error" first and then the "warnings". I want to remove this ordering so that the commands move to closest "problem"

```js
1  _ // -> cursor position
2  const package = require('package') // -> warning - missing semicolon
3  const badPackage require('bad-package // -> error
```

If I were to run `marker.next` in the above code with my cursor at line 1 I would jump to line 3, when I really would prefer to jump to line 2.

Is this possible in VSCode?

It is the default behaviour of `coc.nvim` which gives me hope.

Comment: how are the problems displayed in the PROBLEMS panel, and you are missing a `=` on line 3

Comment: Haha, that is the point! It's an error. The problems in the PROBLEMS panel are displayed errors first, then warnings.

Comment: or it is in the order the providers supply them, the language server and the linter